# How to make Reactjs homepage default as WordPress homepage in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, customization

I have created a page in Reactjs that is a copy of my website's home page. Now I have to make Reactjs page as default page in WordPress site. I need to remove WordPress default homepage and need to add React page.

I just created a build for react code and put that build folder in WordPress root folder and then run the script like http://localhost/my-domain/build it is working fine.

But I want to remove that build folder and want to run straight its code in root folder.

I googled but did not found any solution.

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache configuration? Can you change it on your environment?

Comment: Yes i have access but where I have to change it's environment in apache.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following below the RewriteBase line in your .htaccess file in your WordPress root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/mydomain/build/ [L,R=301]
```